# R lapply into data frame

Tags: r

I have a list contains list as elements. I want to convert all elements into data frame. Instead of using for loop. I used lapply function as follow:

```
myDF=lapply(mylist,FUN=as.data.frame)
```

However it's not converting.

```
class(myDF[1])
```

still returns list.

Any ideas? Thank you so much for your help,

Comment: What is `class(myDF[[1]])`?  I.e. you need to use `[[` instead of `[` to look at the first element of a list as it is.

Comment: @RichardScriven tries to get the class, or type of myDF[1]

Comment: Look at the difference between `myDF[1]` and `myDF[[1]]`

Comment: Cool. Thanks! that's what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look at the first element of the list as-is (i.e. not as a list) you will want to use `[[` instead of `[`. So

```
class(myDF[[1]])
```

will tell you the class of the first list element in `myDF`.

Another way to see this is to look at the difference between `myDF[1]` and `myDF[[1]]`.  `myDF[1]` returns the first element of the list **as a single-element list**, whereas `myDF[[1]]` returns the first element of the list as itself.  See `help(Extract)` for more.